# mp4 file format changed to exe runs in browser

Tags: html, video, web, streaming

Hi i have stumbled up on something really weird I was just testing a download button because I cannot download an mp4 file format on a local server I just changed an mp4 files extension to .exe and when i tried to download the .exe it plays within the browser. whats happening is this streaming the video or is this something random that I have found that should not be done on a website?

Comment: It seems that the browser doesn't look at the file extension but to the MIME type

Comment: within firefox it plays the video within IE it downloads it as a file is there a way to make the browser know its a file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file to be downloaded you should add the extensions to the [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) for example:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Credits to [CSS Tricks - Force Files to Download](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/).

**Update**

If your server is using IIS you should add them as described in this article [Add a MIME Type (IIS7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
For older versions of IIS please see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for the code =D it works perfect the only problem I have got is my testing server is Xammp so the .htaccess will work due to it being apache the only problem I have got is that my live host for this site will be a windows server so the htaccess will not work. so any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer with the info about IIS. If this answers your question please mark it as resolved.